# The dialogflow code is not posting data to the Google Spreadsheet. No bugs logged in Firebox

Tags: axios, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Here is the code. Added hardcoded values for testing.

Axios added to package.json
Enabled fulfillment in Intent.

```js
   
      
  function workerHandler(agent) {
    const {
      name, phone, date
    } = agent.parameters;
   
    const data = [{
      name: "Akash",
      phone: "1234567891",
      date: "5 July"
    }];
    
    axios.post = ('https://sheet.best/api/sheets/------', data);
  }
 
  
  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('saveData', workerHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code.

First, you seem to be doing assignment to `axios.post` rather than trying to call it, although the syntax doesn't look right either. It should be something like

```
axios.post( url, data );
```

You also need to return the Promise that it (and its then/catch) chain returns so Dialogflow's handler dispatcher knows to wait for the Promise to complete. So that might look something more like

```
return axios.post( url, data );
```

but since you want error handling, and you should be sending a response to the user, this might look something more like

```
return axios.post( url, data )
  .then( () => {
    agent.add( "Saved" );
  })
  .catch( err => {
    console.error( err );
    agent.add( "Something went wrong" );
  });
```